# Dynamic Pages scroll down

Tags: python, selenium

I am quite frustrated as my commands do not seem to work. I am trying to load a page and then Python should scroll down the page as much as possible. Here's what I did so far in my Jupyter Notebook:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/')
print(driver.title)
```

That works perfectly. The side is loaded

```
search = driver.find_element_by_name('yfin-usr-qry')
search.send_keys('DAI.DE')
time.sleep(2)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

That works as well the System finds the information for DAI.DE

Then the system should scroll down with the following command:

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
```

and here is the problem. It does not do that, there is nothing happening. But I also do not get an error message, which means that the command should be ok....

Comment: What you provided should work.. scrolling from 0 to the height of the page. This won't scroll to the end of the page. For your comment about the command, just be careful with execute_script, it does not mean that because there is no exception that the command works. If you want to scroll down the list you might get the list of elements and scroll to the last one using ```driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", el)```

Comment: To be more specific, the content load on scrolling. You cannot scroll to the end with one call. So you will need to have logic to scroll and load as many as you need

Comment: Hi Nic, silly question but does el stand for elements?

Comment: It stand for a single element yes. So for example if you get the list of articles (```els = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('YourList'), driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", els[-1])``` This will scroll to the last one that was loaded at that time